# calling jscript function or php function within php

Tags: php, function, echo, jscript

im having trouble calling a function from within php, i have the code right but for some reason the function is not being called, can anybody see any reason why not from this code. Thanks in advance.

The code seems fine and as far as i am aware it should be running the function call, however im pretty new to php so i might have something wrong somewhere but i get no errors from php or jscript , so im not sure if im missing something here. The idea of the code is to change class of a navigation menu..

```
<script>

function removeleftnav(){

document.getElementById('leftnav').classList.remove("leftnavin");
document.getElementById('leftnav').classList.add("leftnavout");

document.getElementById('html').style.width="window.innerwidth";
document.getElementById('mainwrap').classList.remove("mainwrap");

document.getElementById('mainwrap').classList.add("mainwrapnonav");
document.getElementById('centralcolumn').style.left = "0%";
document.getElementById('centralcolumn').style.width="100%";


<?php $showingleftnav="no";?>;

console.log("$phpNO"+"<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");

document.getElementById('leftnavform1').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");
document.getElementById('leftnavform2').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");

document.getElementById('leftnavform3').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");
document.getElementById('leftnavform4').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");

}


</script>



<script>

function retrieveleftnav(){


document.getElementById('leftnav').classList.add("leftnavin");
document.getElementById('leftnav').classList.remove("leftnavout");

document.getElementById('html').style.width="window.innerwidth";

document.getElementById('mainwrap').classList.add("mainwrap");
document.getElementById('mainwrap').classList.remove("mainwrapnonav");

document.getElementById('centralcolumn').style.left = "0%";
document.getElementById('centralcolumn').style.width="83%";

<?php $showingleftnav="yes";?>;

console.log("$phpYES"+"<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");

document.getElementById('leftnavform1').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");
document.getElementById('leftnavform2').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");

document.getElementById('leftnavform3').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");
document.getElementById('leftnavform4').value = ("<?php echo $showingleftnav; ?>");

}

</script>


<?php echo "should be changing here"; ?>

<?php if ($showingleftnav=="yes") { echo" <script>
 function () { retrieveleftnav(); }; </script> "; };

if ($showingleftnav=="no") { echo" <script> 
function() {removeleftnav(); }; </script> "; };

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to keep in mind here.  First is that PHP will run this file from top to bottom to generate an HTML page for you.  In your code, `$showingleftnav` will *always* equal "yes" by the time you get to the bottom of the page.  This is because the PHP code will execute on the server, before the JavaScript runs in the browser.

It looks like you want to call a specific JS function based on the value of that PHP variable.  To get that working, I would suggest you use something more dynamic like a [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable and pass that value in via the URL rather than hard-coding its value in the script.

That said, I think the real issue is that your JavaScript calls are not actually invoking your JS methods.

To get what you have to work, I would suggest something more like at the end of the file (again, using a GET parameter rather than the hard-coded one):

```
<?php 
    if ($_GET['showingleftnav'] == "yes") { 
        echo " retrieveleftnav();";
    } else {
        echo " removeleftnav();";
    }
```